RestTemplate Mocking not working in Junit
I have this method and tried everything but mocking is not working as expected
@Override
    public ClaimSubmissionResponse generateJsonFileProfessional(String claimType, String correlationId,
            String jsonContent, String authToken) {
        ClaimSubmissionResponse claimSubmissionResponse = new ClaimSubmissionResponse();
        try {
            if (isSelfServicePortalServerAvailable(selfServicePortalURL)) {
                HttpHeaders headers = populateTokenHeaders(authToken);
                String corelationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(jsonContent, headers);
                String claimSubmissionAPI = selfServicePortalURL + Endpoints.SUBMIT_CLAIM_PROFESSIONAL;
                processRequestAudit(jsonContent, corelationId, corelationId, ipAddress.toString(), "Generate Json File",
                        "Claim Submission");
                UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(claimSubmissionAPI)
                        .queryParam("claimType", claimType).queryParam("correlationId", correlationId);
                ResponseEntity<ClaimSubmissionResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                        builder.buildAndExpand().toUri(), HttpMethod.POST, request, ClaimSubmissionResponse.class);
                claimSubmissionResponse = response.getBody();
                processResponseAudit(claimSubmissionResponse, "", corelationId, corelationId);
            } else {
                log.info(SELF_SERVICE_PORTAL_UNAVAILABLE_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            log.error("The Error While Executing the API Call :: {} ", cause.getMessage());
        }
        return claimSubmissionResponse;
    }


junit test case

 @Test
public void testGenerateJsonFileProfessional_Success() throws Exception {
    // Mocking external methods and variables
    String claimType = "type1";
    String correlationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String jsonContent = "{}";
    String authToken = "token123";
    String corelationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    // Mocking isSelfServicePortalServerAvailable
    when(selfServiceCoreClaimImpl.isSelfServicePortalServerAvailable(selfServicePortalURL)).thenReturn(true);
    // Mocking populateTokenHeaders
    when(selfServiceCoreClaimImpl.populateTokenHeaders(authToken)).thenReturn(httpHeaders);
    // Mocking RestTemplate response
    ClaimSubmissionResponse expectedResponse = new ClaimSubmissionResponse();
    ResponseEntity<ClaimSubmissionResponse> mockResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(expectedResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    // UriComponentsBuilder mock setup
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(selfServicePortalURL)
            .queryParam("claimType", claimType)
            .queryParam("correlationId", correlationId);
    when(restTemplateTest.exchange(
            builder.buildAndExpand().toUri(), HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(jsonContent, httpHeaders), ClaimSubmissionResponse.class))
        .thenReturn(mockResponse);
    // Call the method under test
    ClaimSubmissionResponse actualResponse = selfServiceCoreClaimImpl.generateJsonFileProfessional(claimType, correlationId, jsonContent, authToken);
    // Assertions
    assertNotNull(actualResponse);
    assertEquals(expectedResponse, actualResponse);
    // Verify RestTemplate was called
    verify(restTemplateTest).exchange(
            builder.buildAndExpand().toUri(), HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(jsonContent, httpHeaders), ClaimSubmissionResponse.class);
}

}
getting this eeror

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:

you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods cannot be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
at com.acentra.ssp.impl.SelfServiceCoreClaimImplTest.testGenerateJsonFileProfessional_Success(SelfServiceCoreClaimImplTest.java:170)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)


Not sure where i am doing wrong. Thanks if someone can help. I stuck in this from past 2 days. tried everthing but not worked.
updated the test method to this :
 @Test
public void testGenerateJsonFile_Success() {
    ClaimSubmissionResponse mockResponse = new ClaimSubmissionResponse();
    ResponseEntity<ClaimSubmissionResponse> responseEntity = mock(ResponseEntity.class);
    when(responseEntity.getBody()).thenReturn(mockResponse);
    when(restTemplate.exchange(any(), eq(HttpMethod.POST), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(ClaimSubmissionResponse.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity);

    ClaimSubmissionResponse response = selfServiceCoreClaimImpl.generateJsonFileProfessional("claimType", "correlationId", "jsonContent", "testdata");
    assertNotNull(response);
}

then
response is getting null here
ResponseEntity<ClaimSubmissionResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                        builder.buildAndExpand().toUri(), HttpMethod.POST, request, ClaimSubmissionResponse.class);
                claimSubmissionResponse = response.getBody();

error is

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException:
Unnecessary stubbings detected.
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code):


-> at com.impl.SelfServiceCoreClaimImplTest.testGenerateJsonFile_Success(SelfServiceCoreClaimImplTest.java:147)
-> at com.impl.SelfServiceCoreClaimImplTest.testGenerateJsonFile_Success(SelfServiceCoreClaimImplTest.java:148)
Please remove unnecessary stubbings or use 'lenient' strictness. More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class.
at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.afterEach(MockitoExtension.java:192)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)


The MissingMethodInvocationException usually pops up when you try to use the when() function on something that's not actually a mock. This can happen if restTemplateTest hasn't been set up correctly as a mock or if there's a problem with how you're using mock() or @Mock annotations.
Double-check restTemplateTest: Make sure you've annotated restTemplateTest with @Mock. Also, don’t forget to initialize your mocks—either in a @Before method or by using MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(). If you're working with a testing framework like Spring Boot, using @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) should handle this part for you.

@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplateTest;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SelfServiceCoreClaimImplTest {

all done with this

Use any(URI.class) for the URI in the exchange mock, as UriComponentsBuilder dynamically creates the URI, and mocking a specific URI might not match and ensure that the HttpMethod.POST, HttpEntity, and response class (ClaimSubmissionResponse.class) are correctly stubbed with eq() and any().

when(restTemplate.exchange(
any(URI.class), eq(HttpMethod.POST), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(ClaimSubmissionResponse.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity);

not working with this as well, it is going inside resttemplate call.

Add @InjectMocks annotation where you have defined instance for selfServiceCoreClaimImpl in test class. That should help in injecting the mocks that you have defined in the test case.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
